# double click event doesn't fire on datagridviewcomboboxcell

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a datagridview and i need to write something on celldoubleclick. that works fine for all the cells except a comboboxcell. It works for the first time but once the focus is on the comboboxcell then it doesn't work. I tried to put editmode programatically now double click works but it doesn't display my combobox items. So I set the editmode to EditOnEnter now it shows all the items but double click doesn't work. It's like endless cycle.

Any one can please give any solution??

Comment: Try creating your own inherited (extended) version of `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` (and `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`), trap the edit control's `MouseDoubleClick` event, and pass it through.

Comment: Thanks for your reply iC. Thats what I am doing. I am extending the datagridview. But I can do something only once I get celldoubleclick event fired.